# Compile-time time in milliseconds

Tags: c++, macros, metaprogramming

Please note that this question differs from many others about getting time in milliseconds.

I want to be able to define a macro that holds the time in milliseconds at the moment of compilation.

The known macro `__TIME__` has the format `HH:MM:SS`, so it doesn't solve the problem. I don't see any other way.

**EDIT**:

To clarify a bit more, I'm trying to generate a random number that can be shared between all the source files at compile time. That number should be the same for all files. My idea was to get the time in milliseconds and then truncate a part of it.

Comment: Quick question: Why do you need it?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/): You tell us what you want, but you don't tell us why you want it, or what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: The reason is enough to write a much bigger question. I'm trying to generate a fixed number that is different on each compilation, but is the sabe between all the files compiled in the project.

Comment: is using -D on the command line to the compiler an option ?

Comment: @karliwson You might write that another question too, but first of all, why do you need to do that?

Comment: @karliwson What about partial recompilations ? Your best bet is to centralize this number into an `extern const` variable that you define in a single file, and increment it externally (e.g. with a Bash script) every time you build. This way you get a unique number each time you *link*.

Comment: Does this need to be a compile time constant?

Comment: So you want each source file to have a specific and unique identifier, each time it is compiled? There's no standard C++ way of handling that. Your build environment is probably better at handling that, perhaps by creating a hash with the source file name and the files modified time-stamp. Or do you mean like a build-number, that each *build* get a unique identifier? Then just have the build system keep an index of the builds, and each build it is incremented by one.

Comment: @Quentin, I'd like to avoid external manipulation, but I will do it if there's no other way.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, the generated number is a single number shared with all the files in the project.

Comment: So basically a build number. Then the build system is definitely the best place to handle that.